# How do I download this image from this URL using URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm trying to download an image from this URL:

> https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSCLjkOCer-xuhkZuvvk3LJYiem4YkAJ869lUXSei5OtZ-SDLWi&usqp=CAU

Using URL session:

```
guard let newURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: newURL), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
    // Failed
    return
}

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

session.downloadTask(with: url).resume()
```

I'm getting the callback in the delegate, and the **status code is 404**.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    if let response = downloadTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 404 {
        return
    }

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: location), let image = UIImage(data: data) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you have a url string, `addingPercentEncoding` breaks the url.

You are not showing the content of the original `url` (String) clearly, but this code works as expected:

```
        let urlString = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSCLjkOCer-xuhkZuvvk3LJYiem4YkAJ869lUXSei5OtZ-SDLWi&usqp=CAU"

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Bad url string: \(urlString)")
            return
        }

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        session.downloadTask(with: url).resume()
```